# Snowflake Warehouse credit calculation - Is it charged per query or is it charged as per the Warehouse time when it is switched on

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Say, for example, I am using XS size cluster and have kept an auto suspend option as 60 Mins.

Consider its suspended for now and I run a query which gets completed in 2 mins(120 Sec) and I do not do anything after that.

So now in this case will I be changed for:

a) 120 Sec CPU time or

b)  complete 1  hour as the Warehouse is switched on and not in suspended mode.

c) Credits charges for 2 Mins + some other charge(minimal charge for other 58 Mins) wherein the Machine is just switched on and not running any credits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it charged per query or is it charged as per the Warehouse time when it is switched on?

The billing is on the time you keep your warehouse running, with a minimum charge of 60 seconds.

For your scenario, per the [Snowflake credits documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/credits.html) you will be billed a total of **3600** seconds of use in credits, covering the *entire* hour the warehouse cluster is left running (even if no queries are run):

> Warehouses are […] billed for credit usage when they are running